# SharePoint error: Web application at xxxx could not be found exception

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

When I try to execute this code:
This is my console application. I logged in as different user. 
using (SPSite objsite = new SPSite(spSiteURL))
It throws the following error:

The Web application at could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.

Answer (score 0):

You should run code under Sharepoint Administrator user and only on Sharepoint farm computer.Remote doesnt work.